# Appian RPA process does not run

Tags: business-process-management, rpa, appian

I'm new to Appian, and have created an RPA process by importing a .side Selenium file. This has created a new section in the workflow.

I've tried running this but whenever I attempt to test it, or to trigger it from a process flow it remains queued forever.

Will the sections exectute automatically one after the other, or do I need to add some command to make the process move from one section to the next?

[image: newly imported process]

[image: queue]

Answer (score 0):

**Debug in Appian RPA**

Appian RPA includes a debugging tool to walk you through the workflow action-by-action and isolate where issues might arise. To use the tool, you'll select Debugging? when you manually execute the robotic process in the Appian RPA console.

Go to the Robotic processes tab.
Find the robotic process you want to debug in the list.
Click the Execute icon rpa-execute-icon.png in the Actions column. Alternatively, you can find the Execute icon at the top of the robotic process configuration page.
In the Execution options, check the Debugging? checkbox.
Click the Execute icon rpa-execute-icon.png once more to start the execution.

https://docs.appian.com/suite/help/21.4/rpa-7.12/create/troubleshoot.html